# Is it okay to validate user input by comparing it to a string?

Tags: php

The user input is expected to be one of several certain strings.

Instead of using a regular expression to validate user input, would it be okay to compare the input to the strings using an `if()` or `switch()` statement?

Usually I would do something like

```
$type = preg_replace('/[^\w\s\d]/', '', trim($_GET['type']));
```

But would it be okay to do

```
switch ($_GET['type']) {
  case 'test': ...code...; break;
  ...more cases....
  default: exit;
}
```

So if the user input is none of the expressions allowed it exits.

Or is `$_GET['type']` maybe evaluated in the `switch()` statement?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, if you need to use the value of `type` to do something, then um do it.

Comment: Q: If you know which could be the input, why not to use a select input?

If you use a string to check the user input in a switch statement, then the default will take all of the non-deserved values. be careful with case sensitive. 

I dont see any problem with that code. Using an if(), the else statement will do the same as default in switch

Comment: @QSoto, that is not the question that I'm asking. (BTW: the interface does not call for a dropdown. )

Comment: I don't see any problem comparing against an string. Of course it could be a support hell in the future. When I face this kind of comparations I use constraints for easy change and re-use

Comment: `switch` does a loose comparison (==) a user could possibly trick the code, its safer to use strict comparison (===) at least i think this is what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use `in_array` to validate input against a list of specific acceptable values.

```
if (!in_array($_GET['type'], $array_of_acceptable_values, true)) {
    // handle the error condition with exit; or whatever you decide to do
}
```

This has a couple of advantages over hard-coding the acceptable values in a control structure, in my opinion.

- less code
- simpler to update the list of values if needed
- easy to load the value list from another source (config file, etc.) if you decide to do that

Comment: This is one of the solutions I thought of. But as I understand, there's no problem not sanitizing the user input when using it only to compare against valid strings?

Comment: should add the strict comparison toggle here or it uses a loose comparison.

Comment: If the input can only be certain specific values, there shouldn't be any need to sanitize it before comparing to that list of values, whether you do it this way or with the switch approach.

Comment: @tim, thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I'll use the in_array(needle, haystack, TRUE) solution.